# Xtext: Content assist for indent aware languages

Tags: xtext

For xtext languages to become indent aware, synthetic tokens are used [as described here](https://eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/307_special_languages.html). But, at the indented locations, content assist is not proposing anything unless the first letter is typed.

For example, consider the following grammar:

```html
Model:
 lines += Line+;
 
Line:
  'model' name=ID
  BEGIN
   type=(Type1 | Type2 | Type3)
  END
;

Type1:
'type1:' attr=ID;

Type2:
'type2:' attr=ID;

Type3:
'type3:' attr=ID;

// The following synthetic tokens are used for the indentation-aware blocks
terminal BEGIN: 'synthetic:BEGIN';  // increase indentation
terminal END: 'synthetic:END';      // decrease indentation
```

Now, after typing model and a new line and a tab, content assist does not prompt anything. But, if I type t and then ask for content assist, I get type1, type2 and type3.

Why does the content assist work only upon partial typing?

Answer (score 0):

Your grammar rule states that the type information is mandatory between `BEGIN` and `END` tokens in the rule `Line`. I would assume that the parser is showing strange error recovery behavior if you omit the type there. It'll probably help if you mark the type as optional.

Comment: In this case, I am trying to implement a white-space sensitive language. I wish to use the content assist to prompt for the different types possible at that location. Right now, hitting ctrl+space after typing 'model', new line and tab returns nothing. But, if I type the letter 't' after that, the parser recognises that the types and prompts me with 'type1, type2 and type3'. 

How do I modify the behaviour of synthetic tokens?

Comment: Marking it as optional did not help